# How to process Result of StringReplace?

Tags: string-manipulation

```
StringReplace["item_10", "item_" ~~ x__ -> x + 1]
```

returns "1+10"

How can I force it to evaluate to 11?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: To `11` or `"11"`?

Comment: Related: [(4230)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4230/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns `"11"`:

```
StringReplace["item_10",  "item_" ~~ x__ :> ToString[ToExpression[x] + 1] ]
StringReplace["item_10",  "item_" ~~ x__ :> ToString[ToExpression[x <> "+1"]] ]
```

This `11`:

```
StringCases["item_10", "item_" ~~ x__ :> ToExpression[x] + 1]
StringCases["item_10", "item_" ~~ x__ :> ToExpression[x <> "+1"]]
```

And step by step, first of all, `:>` not `->`, the latter, `Rule`, is evaluated immediately:

```
x = 5;
StringReplace["item_10", "item_" ~~ x__ -> x]
StringReplace["item_10", "item_" ~~ x__ :> x]
```

> ```
> StringExpression[5]
> 10
> ```

Then, you get a string `"10"`, not a number so you have to perform appriopriate conversion first.

Comment: If working with integers using `FromDigits` is "safer" than `ToExpression`.